# Is it possible to register a click event on a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose you have a dynamic profile page. When the user clicks on the edit button, some *divs* in the page become functional. E.g. when the user clicks the *div*, something happens with it.
So I use the **JQuery Click()** event on those *divs*. But I only want to register this when the page is in ***edit-mode***. Currently I have something like this:

```
$(".someClass").click(function() {
    if(editMode) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

But isn't this kinda inefficient? Because it registers the click event even when it isn't in editMode. What I would like to achieve is something like:

```
if(editMode) {
    $(".someClass").click(function() {
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

Obviously this won't work. Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: why do you say the second version does not work

Comment: except that you will have to remove the handler if the condition is not met - if it is already added (look at `.off()` and event name spaces)

Comment: because that just doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/QuantumHive/uH8r5/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kwZ6e/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time you go into edit mode, you can bind all the handlers. Then when the user leaves edit mode, you can unbind them with:

```
$(".someClass").off("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but using `.on()` event handler attachment like

```
if(editMode) {
    $(document).on('click', ".someClass", function() {
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

then you can detach this event handler using **`.off()`**

```
$(".someClass").off("click");
```

Comment: But this doesn't remove the handlers when he leaves edit mode.

Comment: @Barmar I thought that Op wants to attach an event based on condition, then I planned to add details about detaching it using .off() event handler attachment.  Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class eg: 'edit' on the container when in edit mode, remove it when not.

```
$(document).on('click', ".edit .someClass", function() {
   //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is this:

1. Add a class in your condition to the target elem
2. make a click handler to that class name with `.on()` method

---

```
if(editMode) {
   $(".someClass").addClass('editable');
}

$(".someClass closest static parent elem").on('click', '.editable', function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

#### note:

```
$(".someClass closest static parent elem")
```

you can change it to `$(document)` too but better to use the closest static parent elem to that target element.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems

syntax error in `function AnimateTile(id, z, w, h, now = true) {`, you can do it instead do something like

```
function AnimateTile(id, z, w, h, now) {
    now = now == undefined ? true : now;
```

then the edit handler must be in the click handler because whenever the value of `edit` changes you need to either add the handler or remove it.

```
$(".bigtile").click(function (event) {
    edit = !edit;
    if (edit) $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    else $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    if (edit) {
        $(".tile").on('click.edit', function (event) {
            clicked = !clicked;
            if (clicked) {
                switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
                    case "tile1":
                        AnimateTile("tile1", 100, 210, 210);
                        break;
                    case "tile2":
                        AnimateTile("tile2", 100, 210, 210);
                        break;
                    case "tile3":
                        AnimateTile("tile3", 100, 210, 210);
                        break;
                    case "tile4":
                        AnimateTile("tile4", 100, 210, 210);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
                    case "tile1":
                        AnimateTile("tile1", 0, 100, 100, false);
                        break;
                    case "tile2":
                        AnimateTile("tile2", 0, 100, 100, false);
                        break;
                    case "tile3":
                        AnimateTile("tile3", 0, 100, 100, false);
                        break;
                    case "tile4":
                        AnimateTile("tile4", 0, 100, 100, false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".tile").off('click.edit');
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kwZ6e/)

Also read [event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names), and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off)